# Ionic 5 Dynamically change primary color

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, css-variables

I am trying to make my Ionic Angular app's color scheme change based on events that happen while using the app. The app is quite large with many components that all need to be aware of the color change when it happens. Ideally I would like to know of a way to have my elements reference a color(s) (let's say --primary) and to be able to change that color in one place and have all the elements respond to the change.

I have not found anything in the Ionic docs that references being able to change the CSS variable definitions at runtime so I have looked at instead swapping which variable I use at runtime.

I have considered listing many different colors in the variables.scss and then using ngClass to apply a globally defined class name that can respond to the change. The downside of this is I would have to anticipate and individually declare each possible attribute that needs the color. For example, I could use [ngClass]="primary-1" to apply a class defined like this:

```
.primary-1 {
background: var(--ion-color-primary-1);
}
```

but if I wanted to use an element that needed the background-color attribute I would also need a different class for that attribute:

```
.primary-1-other {
background-color: var(--ion-color-primary-1) 
}
```

My problem is that I do not want the global class definitions to be aware of the specific element attributes unless there is a concise and comprehensive way to do that.

I have also looked into using setProperty but as far as I can tell that only changes styles in the specific context rather than the app as a whole.

Any solutions/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
const htmlEl = document.querySelector('html');
htmlEl.style.setProperty('--ion-color-primary', '#0000ff');
```

Thanks @XML for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to modify Ionic's Global CSS Variables. They are a bunch of runtime modifiable variables. You're in luck, because in the old days, you could only modify those variables at compile time. Now, there are methods to modify at runtime.

This guide explains how: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables

Comment: This page references using the setProperty method which modifies the attributes of a single selector. Is it possible to find the reference for `:root` and modify the global variables? The docs linked in that section say this in the description: _We know that the rule we want to alter to do this is contained inside the second stylesheet applied to the page, so we grab a reference to it using document.styleSheets[1]_ How could I know which stylesheet `:root` is in?

Comment: I don't believe you need to know which sheet it's in. Once those sheets are read into DOM, I believe they're globally accessible. What I think you want are the global color variables, described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors